# ORACLE: Constraint to restrict number of issues an article may be in

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, assertion

Stuck on this question in a revision paper. I've left the other relations out as they're not relevant to the question.

Consider the following relation:
Article(arID, title, journal, issue, year, startpage, endpage)

How would I go about making a constraint that makes sure no more than 5 articles may be published in one particular issue?

Would I do something like:

```
CREATE ASSERTION ArticlesInIssue
CHECK(
(SELECT COUNT(Issue) FROM Article) <= 5);
```

I think this wouldn't work fully as it wouldn't be counting for the specific issue, right? So would I need a where clause, or am I going in the totally wrong direction here?
Thanks,
Mo.

Comment: What flavour of SQL?  MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle?

Comment: The condition specified in the CHECK clause should evaluate to a boolean and cannot use queries or environment functions such as SYSDATE, USER, USERENV, AND UID.  Do you have to use a constraint or can you use a procedure?

Comment: Oracle doesn't actually support SQL assertions. (Do *any* DBMSes?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a *[trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm)* that fires upon insert. You can write SQL in the trigger to query the table about-to-be-inserted and do that check. Your code will need to explicitly rollback the insert.

I hope you have an index on the issue column!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to add an `articleNo NUMBER(1) NOT NULL` column and the constraints:

```
UNIQUE (issue, articleNo)
```

and

```
CHECK (articleNo BETWEEN 1 AND 5)
```